# How to run multiple blocking IO coroutines in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I have a long running pipeline implemented with coroutines. This is typically fetching log streams, performing some enrichment(threaded) and writing them to a data-store.

Here is a small example to simulate the pipeline:

```
import time
import random
from concurrent import futures

def coroutine(func):
    def start(*args, **kwargs):
        cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
        next(cr)
        return cr
    return start

@coroutine
def foo():
    pool = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
    while True:
        i = (yield)
        fut = pool.submit(enrich, i)
        fut.add_done_callback(result_handler)
        time.sleep(random.random()*10)

def enrich(i):
    enriched = 'foo' + str(i)
    time.sleep(random.random())
    return enriched

def source(name, target):
    while True:
        time.sleep(random.random())
        i = random.randint(0,10)
        target.send(name + str(i))
```

A single pipeline invoked as follows works fine.

```
source('task one ', foo())
```

Now, I'd like to run multiple pipelines for different logs in background threads. One attempt is to use ThreadPoolExecutor again to drive multiple pipelines.

```
def run():
    pool = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
    tasks = [source('task one ', foo()),
             source('task two ', foo())]
    for task in tasks:
        fut = pool.submit(task)
        fut.add_done_callback(result_handler)
```

However, the pipeline blocks after the first task and never gets to do the second task. What's the correct way to run such long running (maybe forever) pipelines in background threads?

Comment: In `run` function you pass result of `source('task one ', foo()` to `pool.submit(task)`. It should be `pool.submit(source, 'task one', foo())`

Comment: Or, `tasks = [(source, 'task one', foo()), (source, 'task two', foo())]`. Then `pool.submit(`*task)`

Comment: Excellent! That solves the simulated problem I presented here. The actual pipeline is quite involved and I still get some callback exception that I will have to check. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Let me post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `source` function is never-ending, the `tasks = [source('task one ', foo()), source('task two ', foo())]` list is not created. That's why the first task runs and the pipelne blocks.
The solution is to pass `source` and its arguments to `pool.submit`.

```
tasks = [(source, 'task one', foo()), (source, 'task two', foo())]
for task in tasks:
    fut = pool.submit(*task)
    fut.add_done_callback(result_handler)
```